# Why is only one field being set when creating a new document in firebase when being passed multiple fields?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a document in my "Users" collection with multiple fields (role,email,createdAt). I have these fields and the associated data store in a "data" variable and set the doc to the object. The issue is only the email field is being assigned and the rest aren't showing up in the doc in Firebase.

I have tried variations of using an object directly in the set() or setting the fields directly there in {}, it didn't seem to make much of a difference.

```
this.data = { email: this.email, role: "new", createdAt: this.timestamp};

console.log("user", user);
          console.log("uid", user.user.uid);
          let docRef = db
            .collection("Users")
            .doc(user.user.uid)
            .set(this.data)
            .then(function() {
              console.log("Document successfully written!");
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
          console.log(this.data);
          return docRef.then(res => {
            console.log("Set: ", res);
            this.$router.push("/welcome");
          });
```

All of the console logs are as expected except the "Set" console log being Null.Only the email field is showing up on the newly created doc.

EDIT: Figured it out, a Cloud Function was running on account creation and was creating a doc in the "Users" collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Doug Stevenson has already answered your question - to get the contents you just added you'll need to query it from Firebase. But just to add a bit more, it looks like you'd probably like to wait until the data is added to change the route, in which case you may want to try something like this:

```
db
.collection("Users")
.doc(user.user.uid)
.set(this.data)
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
    // After you know the data has been written, you can query it.
    db.collection("Users").doc(user.user.uid).get().then((res) => {
        // Log the data from the response
        console.log(res.data())
        resolve()
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        reject(err)
    })
    // Then change the route.
    this.$router.push("/welcome");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `docRef` is a promise that comes from the return value of `catch()`.  That promise isn't going to resolve with the contents of the document that was just added.  Not even the promise returned by [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#set) is going to give you the contents.  If you want to query for the contents of that document, you'll have to use get() on a reference to the document.

```
db.collection("Users").doc(user.user.uid).get(snap => {
    // snap is a snapshot that contains the fields of the document
})
```